# Why don't logarithms work here?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have this problem:

For what values of $x$ is $x^6 \ge x^8$?

I solved this by the following.

\begin{align}
x^6 & \ge x^8 \\
\Longrightarrow \quad 1 & \ge x^2 \\
\end{align}
Therefore $$ -1 \le x \le 1 $$

When using the power identity for logarithms however, and dividing by $\ln x$, the answer is $6 \ge 8$. Why?

$$x^6 \ge x^8$$
$$6\ln x \ge 8\ln x$$
$$6 \ge 8$$

Comment: Write out the steps using the log. Don't forget that $\text{ln}(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$. Be careful with reasonings such that "canceling out".

Comment: $x\le 1~\color{Red}{or}~x\ge-1$ should be *and*.

Comment: When working with inequalities you must be careful about dividing through / multiplying through, as the direction of the inequality flips with negative numbers.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/451/

Comment: @RenéG My first thought as well.

Comment: Your first solution isn't rigorous. You are dividing by $x$ so that you should exclude $x=0$ (and treat it separately), which you didn't.

Comment: @arctic: $0 \leq x \leq 1$ **or** $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ would be a more direct expression of the intent.

Comment: @Hurkyl I was responding to a line from a previous version of the question (now edited away in light of my comment).

Comment: @arctic: Yes; the line that, to my eye, looks like it came from breaking the problem into two parts (take the positive square root and take the negative square root). "Or" would be the correct way to join the two solutions; the error was failing to notate the other bound. The end result is logically equivalent to your correction, of course.

Comment: @Hurkyl "or" would be the correct way to join the two inequalities you typed, not the two that were originally given by the OP. (The way the OP did it, modulo the and/or error, is the way the intermediate algebra book I teach out of handles splitting $|x|\le k$ up, if that's relevant.) Not sure why you're bringing any of this up or addressing it to me specifically rather than the OP.

Comment: Amazing to look back on my own questions from almost 7 years ago. How simple they were in hindsight!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your calculations:

$$x^6\geq x^8 \Leftrightarrow \ln(x^6)\geq \ln(x^8)$$

Here we must have $x\neq 0$, because $\ln(0)$ is not well-defined. So you have to check if the inequality holds for $x=0$ separately. (It does hold).

Now you want to use $$\ln(x^6)=6\cdot\ln(x)\geq 8\cdot\ln(x)=\ln(x^8).$$ This only holds for $x>0$, as $\ln(x)$ is only well-defined for $x>0$. Be sure to always check the requirements when using such rules. So for now we can only continue with the assumption $x>0$.

Your next step would be to divide both sides by $\ln(x)$. We can only do this, if $\ln(x)\neq 0$ which is equivalent to $x\neq 1$. So you also have to check if the inequality holds for $x=1$ separately (it does hold).

Assuming that we have $x>0$ and $x\neq 1$ we can now divide by $\ln(x)$. But because we are dealing with an inequality, we have to be careful and take a look at the sign of $\ln(x)$:
$$\ln(x)>0 \Leftrightarrow x>1,\quad \ln(x)<0 \Leftrightarrow 0<x<1.$$
So we have to distinguish two cases:

If $x>1$ we have:
$$x^6\geq x^8 \Leftrightarrow \ln(x^6)\geq \ln(x^8) \Leftrightarrow 6\ln(x)\geq 8\ln(x) \Leftrightarrow 6\geq 8.$$ 
This is not true, thus the inequality doesn't hold for $x>1$.

For $0<x<1$ we get:
$$x^6\geq x^8 \Leftrightarrow \ln(x^6)\geq \ln(x^8) \Leftrightarrow 6\ln(x)\geq 8\ln(x) \Leftrightarrow 6\leq 8.$$
This is true, thus the inequality holds for $0<x<1$.

We now have to do the same steps again for $x<0$, using that in this case we have $$\ln(x^6)=6\cdot\ln(-x),\ln(x^8)=8\cdot\ln(-x).$$ (I don't feel like writing the same steps again...)

The problem that arose with your calculations is, that you just applied some rule you heard of without carefully checking if you are allowed to apply this rule. Also to "just cancel out" often leads to problems, when one doesn't check that there is no $0$ involved that might get canceled.

Another (personal) remark: why would one use logarithms to solve this inequality? Just because it is possible to solve this question, doesn't mean that one should do it (you can see that a correct use of logarithms leads to a very long solution with lots of cases one has to think about).

Comment: This one well answers "Why?" concerning the `ln(x)` part in a nice step-by-step way.

Comment: It might be worth reiterating towards the end that the three cases $x \in \{ -1, 0, 1\}$ still need to be done.

Comment: To add to the last paragraph: logarithms are indeed really overkill here. All you have to do is think that when you multiply something by a factor greater than 1, the thing increases, and when you multiply by a factor between 0 and 1, it decreases, so that $x^6\leq x^8$ is indeed equivalent to $0\leq x \leq 1$ (for positive $x$).

Comment: I assume that the OP was looking for insight into why the two methods gave divergent answers - perhaps logarithms are new, or perhaps they represent the OP's most intuitive tactic. In any event, asking 'why would you do it that way?' in math seems short-sighted not only because every legal way should give correct results, but because most of us are still learning math and it's wise to check our work.

Answer (score 28):

$\ln x$ is negative when $0<x<1$, so when you cancel that you may need to invert the inequality depending on what $x$ is.

(And, of course, taking logarithms does not work well for negative $x$ at all).

Comment: Why wouldn't log(-x) work? It's just a complex number.

Comment: @Navin: Because (a) $\log(x^y)=y\log x$ does not work in general unless $x$ and $y$ are both positive reals, and (b) inequalities do not work _at all_ for complex numbers.

Answer (score 10):

You can't divide both side to $x^8$ hence $0$ holds inequation.Furthermore,the solution of inequation is $${ x }^{ 6 }\left( x-1 \right) \left( x+1 \right) \le 0$$

> $$x\in [-1 ,1]$$

Next step is clear from the answer above

Comment: You made a little error in sign, since clearly $(-2)^6$ is not greater than $(-2)^8$. The situation is symmetric, so the right interval is $[-1,1]$. But your method is far superior, since it does not follow OP’s false lead to use logarithms.

Comment: @Lubin,thanks it was a silly mistake

Comment: You cannot write "the answer above" an expect it to be understood what you're talking about. The order that the site presents answers in changes dynamically depending on vote counts (or whichever other sorting criteria _the user has chosen_), so you cannot predict whether the answer you're thinking of will be shown above or below yours.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend to you never to “cancel”. Rather, you want to do the same thing to both sides of an equation; or, under suitable circumstances, to both sides of an inequality; or to multiply top and bottom of a fraction by the same thing.

So you took the inequality $x^6\ge x^8$. It’s not at all clear what you meant by the “logarithm identity”, but probably you took the log of both sides, to get $6\ln x\ge8\ln x$. Now what? If $\ln x$ is positive, you divide both sides by it and get the false inequality $6\ge8$. but if $\ln x$ is zero, you get a true equality $0=0$, and this is fine. Also, if $\ln x$ is negative, when you divide both sides of $6\ln x\ge8\ln x$ by $\ln x$, *the inequality reverses*, giving you the valid inequality $6\le  8$.

Conclusion? We get $\ln x\le0$, in other words $0<x\le1$.

Comment: I should delete this answer, because that of @Battani is so much better. But I want the sermon to stay.

Comment: You should correct that little bit where you say $x^6 = 6 \ln x$. (Think negative)

Comment: I don’t think I could possibly have said just that, @AlexR . But I *should* have said $3\ln(x^2)\ge4\ln(x^2)$, and have cast the rest of the argument in those terms.

Comment: Yet, your answer still contains this minor mistake...

Answer (score 6):

Canceling the logs is not a valid step because it's possible that $\ln x = 0$.  This happens when $x=1$, which is a valid solution value for the original inequality.  So canceling like that can cause solutions to be lost.

Also, $\ln x$ can be negative.  In this case you'll need to reverse the inequality sign.  This happens when $0 < x < 1$.

If you're very careful, you can get *part* of the right answer by taking logs.  But this method should still be avoided because it loses solutions.  And the biggest reason of all, when you take logs and then use the log power rule as you did, you completely remove $x \le 0$ from the domain, and in general this can lead (and does in this case) to more lost solutions.

Note that dividing both sides by $x^8$ is also not valid because this is not allowed if $x=0$.  It still leads to the right answer but that's a happy accident.  If you do that method on an assignment, test, etc., you're likely to lose points.

The proper way to do this problem is as follows:

\begin{align}
x^6 &\ge x^8\\
x^6 - x^8 &\ge 0\\
x^6(1-x^2) &\ge 0
\end{align}

Equality is obtained when $x=0$ or $x=\pm 1$.  For the strict inequality $x^6(1-x^2) > 0$, this is true if $x^6$ and $1-x^2$ are both positive or if they're both negative.  Note that $x^6$ is never negative.  So the strict inequality is only satisfied when both factors are positive.  $x^6 > 0$ when $x \ne 0$ and $1-x^2 >0$ when $-1 < x < 1$.

Putting everything together tells us the solution is $-1\le x \le 1$, i.e., $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Rolling back the mostly stylistic edits.  Please don't make stylistic edits on my posts.  I'm open to changing "The proper way" to "A proper way" if there is indeed another proper way apart from factoring.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid division issues in the inequality by following this subtraction track. If $x=0$, the inequality is true. If $x\neq 0$, you can take the $\log$ because quantities $x^6$ and $x^8$ are strictly positive.

$x^6 \ge x^8  \implies 6 \log |x| \ge 8 \log |x| \implies (6-8)\log |x| \ge 0$

which implies that $\log |x| \le 0$, or $x\in [-1\; 0[\cup]0\;1]$. Do not forget the absolute value when putting an even power out of a logarithm. Now your set of solutions is included in $\{0\}\cup[-1\; 0[\cup]0\;1] = [-1\;1]$.

If $x\in [-1\;1]$, $x^2\le 1$, hence $x^6 x^2 \le x^6$, so the set of solutions is the whole segment $[-1\;1]$.

Answer (score 3):

From $$x^6\ge x^8,$$ taking the logarithms

$$\log x^6\ge\log x^8$$

follows, provided that both arguments are positive. So we need to handle $x=0$ separately, and this is trivial.

Next, as the exponents are even, we can rewrite (with a mandatory absolute value)

$$6\log|x|\ge8\log|x|,$$ which is just

$$\log|x|\le 0,$$ or

$$0<|x|\le1.$$

---

If you insist on using a division, you need to discuss the sign before simplifying

- $\log|x|>0\implies6\ge8$ which is impossible,
- $\log|x|=0\implies0\ge0$, so that $|x|=1$ are solutions,
- $\log|x|<0\implies6\le8$ so that $0<|x|\le1$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**A contrived argument**:

By inspection, $x=0$ is a solution.

Then without loss of generality, $x>0$, because if $x$ is a solution, so is $-x$. This allows us to write

$$6\log x\ge8\log x.$$

By inspection, $\log x=0$ is a solution.

Then without loss of generality, $\log x> 0$ because if $\log x$ is a solution, $-\log x$ is a non-solution, and conversely. This allows us to write

$$6\ge8$$ and there are no solutions for $\log x$, so that all $-\log x>0$, i.e. $x<1$, are solutions.

Hence

$$x=0\lor(x>0\land x<1\land-x<1).$$