# How to know if $x$ is defined or not?

Tags: logarithms

If we have, say
$$
\log_{10} (1/x)+\log_{10}(4/x)=-2,
$$
then the solution is
$$
x=\pm 20.
$$
But the negative solution is false.

On the other hand, if we rewrite the equation to
$$
\log_{10}(4/x^2)=-2,
$$
then the solution is
$$
x=\pm 20.
$$

Negative solution is OK here since it is $x^2$ in the equation.

Even when I plot the equations it shows different solutions. So how is that working?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889542/why-dont-logarithms-work-here/1889563#1889563) helps.

Comment: a similar problem would be $\sqrt x \sqrt x = 1$ has one solution $x = 1$  But, $\sqrt {x^2} = 1$ has two solutions ($x=\pm1$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the functions you are using have defined values only for positive real numbers.

If you want to be able to take the log of a negative integer, you have to work with complex numbers, where `ln(-1) = πi`.
(It's easier to do with natural logs than with base 10.)

> ln(-1/20) = πi + ln(1/20)
> ln(-1/5) = πi + ln(1/5)
> Sum = ln(1/20) + ln(1/5) + 2πi

When taking logs with complex numbers, `2nπi` is equivalent to 0 (for all integers `n`), since `e`<sup>`2nπi`</sup> is zero.
So the sum of these two values will be the real number you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting $$\log_{10} (1/x)+\log_{10}(4/x)=-2\tag1$$ as $$\log_{10}(4/x^2)=-2\tag2$$ is to apply the identity $$\log_{10} (1/x)+\log_{10}(4/x)\equiv\log_{10}(4/x^2)$$ which has the implicit domain $x>0$ (due to its LHS); on $\mathbb R{\setminus}\{0\},$ equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equivalent.

On the other hand, $$\log_{10}(4/x^2)=-2,\quad x>0\tag3$$ ***is*** an equivalent rewriting of equation $(1).$

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot!! I can see that when i plot the two equation! But it was hard to understand how to explain it!

Comment: OK thanks!! I upvoted your comment!

Answer (score 0):

In all simplicity, the input in the logarithm must be something positive. If some value of $x$ gives you a negative input, then you need to exclude it. In the first example, $x=-20$ gives $-\frac{1}{20}$ and $-\frac{1}{5}$ inside the logarithm, but in the second one it will be positive for both values of $x$.